# Validate timestamp for a particular duration in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp

I want to see whether my data is 120 second old by looking at the timestamp of the data so I have below code:

```
uint64_t now = duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
bool is_old = (120 * 1000 < (now - data_holder->getTimestamp()));
```

In the above code `data_holder->getTimestamp()` is `uint64_t` which returns timestamp in milliseconds. Does my above code looks right?

Comment: Did you try some simple tests? It looks right but that is not a real question

Comment: Yeah I tried it but somehow I was confuse how this `count` is working when I get value for `now` variable. For simple example like this `now: 7853385 data holder timestamp: 1437518224112`. How this is working?

Comment: How are you assigning `data_holder->getTimestamp()`?

Comment: @JonathanMee `data_holder->getTimestamp()` always returns timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
auto now = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
// Use the correct time duration below. Milliseconds could be wrong, see 1)
auto diff = now - std::chrono::milliseconds(data_holder->getTimestamp());
bool is_old = diff > std::chrono::seconds{120};
// bool is_old = diff > 120s; // From C++14 onwards.
```

1) As mentioned, `milliseconds` could be the wrong unit to use for `getTimestamp()`. All possible types are

```
std::chrono::hours
std::chrono::minutes
std::chrono::seconds
std::chrono::milliseconds
std::chrono::microseconds
std::chrono::nanoseconds
```

You probably have to try out which one to use, because that depends on `data_holder->getTimestamp()`.

---

#### Note: Big one

Making sure to use `system_clock` to measure time since epoch will work most likely. But the standard doesn't require that a clock's epoch is **the UNIX epoch**. You have encountered this with `steady_clock` already.

You'd have to calculate the difference between the clock's epoch and the epoch yourself (and I don't know of a way to do that right now for any clock). For `system_clock`, if you don't trust it to use the unix epoch you can use the following:

```
system_clock::duration time_since_unix_epoch()
{
    std::tm epoch;
    epoch.tm_mday = 1;
    epoch.tm_mon = 0;
    epoch.tm_year = 70;
    std::time_t epocht = mktime(&epoch);
    return system_clock::now() - system_clock::from_time_t(epocht);
}
```

instead of `system_clock::now()`. I'd prefer this method.

Unfortunatly you can't just replace `system_clock` with another clock from `std::chrono` because only `std::system_clock` offers `from_time_t(time_t)` which converts a real date to the internal `time_point` used by the clock.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. `data_holder->getTimestamp()` will return timestamp in milliseconds. Can you help me understand this - My now variable value is `10011360` and data holder timestamp value is `1437520382241` then why difference is coming as `18446742636199180735` of `now - data_holder->getTimestamp()`. It should come as negative right?

Comment: The above result is with my code what I have. Any thoughts?

Comment: hmmm that's what I was confuse as well what is count doing. But when I print out now and data holder timestamp, I get above details and if I subtract it, it should be negative then why it is positive?

Comment: Thanks for help. What is the difference between `steady_clock` vs `system_clock`? I was not able to understand this. And also if I need to go with my solution what I had in my question, I can just replace `steady_clock` with `system_clock` right?

Comment: @user1950349, the difference is quite technical. `steady_clock` is guaranteed to never be reset as far as I understood it, thus being monotone, whereas `system_clock` is designed to represent the computer's calendar date. And no, you can't just replace them, see the last paragraph in the answer.